# How to install s3sync

Tags: ruby-on-rails, synchronization, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, rsync

This seems like an excellent script but lacks a key part to its installation I can't seem to figure out. Maybe someone out there can help a newb.

What I've done so far :

1. Installed the s3sync package.
2. Downloaded the s3 certificate
3. Downloaded the s3 ssl package
4. ran it with sh ssh.certs.shar
5. Edited the s3conf.yml file to have the correct AWS id and password and a path to the cert file

When I run the s3cmd.rb I get the error "You didn't set up your environment variables; see README.txt"

To which I agree, there is no information written regarding where I specify destination or target.

Guesses :

-The cert file has to be in a specific place to which it isn't, or its in the incorrect cert file

-the s3conf.yml may not have the correct information written in it.

**UPDATE:**
Uninstalled everything, and installed it as a gem. Made sure the s3config.yml is still in /etc/s3conf/ . Still nothing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some b/s here but I went into the s3config.rb

Found this line :

```
confpath = ["#{ENV['S3CONF']}", "#{ENV['HOME']}/.s3conf", "/etc/s3conf"]
```

and ripped it apart to this :

```
confpath = ["/etc/s3conf"]
```

Done, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The `environment variables` are not being found.  This troubled me for a while.  It is because the locations you are setting in that initial line of `confpath` code `["#{ENV['S3CONF']}"`, ... is not actually the location of the variables contained in the `.yaml` file.

As Trip says, hard setting that value to the dir containing the `.yaml` file solved this problem for me.

You could actually set the values using '`export`' but really, this is much easier!